# ¿Mostrar alert con SweetAlert2 al hacer click, smartphones?

Tags: javascript, html

espero que esten bien.

estoy aqui por un inconveniente que tengo al intentar cerrar sesion desde el movil.

es decir: cuando doy click en el SALIR debe salir una alert que me pregunte si deseeo cerrar sesión.

[image: BOTON SALIR]

mensaje alert:

[image: alert cerrar sesión]

en el navegador de pc funciona correctamente, pero en los movil no me sale nada al presionar el boton salir.

este es mi codigo html boton salir:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="salir-irse">
    <li class="user-footer">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-flat manito-clic" id="salir-irse2">salir</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

este es mi codigo js uso jquery:

```
$(document).on("click","#salir-irse2", function(){
    swal.fire({

        icon: "warning",
        title: "¿ESTAS APUNTO DE CERRAR SESIÓN",
        text: "¡SI DESEA PUEDE PERMANECER EN LA PAGINA!",
        showCancelButton: true,
        showConfirmButton: true,
        cancelButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonText: "QUEDARME",
        confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: "IRME DE PASEO!"

    }).then(function(result){

        if(result.value){

            window.location = "salir";

        }


    })

})
```

Comment: Que version de swal estas usando? Estas utilizando alguna librería de css como bootsrap?, podria ser tema de algun @media que oculte el objeto del swal en esta resolucion

Comment: estoy usando boostrap 3, SweetAlert2 y jquery.